# Paste button disabled, when accessing Wiki from OSX

Tags: wiki, copy-and-paste, mac-os-x

SharePoint Server Enterprise 2010 on multiple servers. Clients have Windows XP, 7 or OSX.

When a user is editing a wiki page from a Windows client, everything is ok. From a Mac, the paste button in the ribbon bar is disabled. But paste via shortcut (cmd+v) works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There hasn't been an API to access the clipboard via JavaScript code until a recent W3C draft has been created. Unfortunately this W3C draft hasn't been implemented yet into any modern Web browser, AFAIK. IIRC it is only in beta testing builds of Google Chrome and Mozilla Firefox.

Only Internet Explorer offers an API accessible via JavaScript/ActiveX/Silverlight, hence you can use the ribbon buttons with IE but they remain disabled on any other Web browser and you are forced to use keyboard shortcuts instead.

Comment: But in Firefox 22 the paste button is enabled ...

Comment: Well, as I mentioned: IIRC (if I remember correctly). It appears my memory is wrong and Firefox v22 already implemented the clipboard API. I was under the impression that it will come with Firefox v23. Google Chrome might probably also have it implemented in v27. Looks like I have to run some tests over the weekend ;-)